# CasperJS back navigation is not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, back

This is my code, the back navigation is not working, because the screen capture is same as previous even though I waited for 2 seconds.

```
phantom.casperPath = "/Users/manoj/apply_robots/casjs/casperjs";
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + "/bin/bootstrap.js");
phantom.injectJs("/Users/manoj/apply_robots/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js");

var utils = require('utils');
var fs = require('fs');
var a;
var flag = 1;

var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16");
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('https://piedmont.taleo.net/careersection/2/moresearch.ftl?lang=en',function(){

    casper.page.injectJs('/Users/manoj/apply_robots/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('#requisitionListInterface\\.dropListSize').selectedIndex = 4;
        return true;
    });

    this.wait(3000,function(){});
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.thenClick(x('//*[@id="requisitionListInterface.pagerDivID4117.Next"]')).then(function() { 

        this.wait(2000,function(){
            this.capture("i1.png");
        });
    });
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.echo("inside back");
    this.back();
    this.wait(3000,function(){
        this.capture("i3.png");
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.thenClick(x('//*[@id="requisitionListInterface.pagerDivID4117.Next"]')).then(function() { 
        this.wait(2000,function(){
            this.capture("i5.png");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is necessary to execute the `back()` call twice in order for it to work:

```
casper.back().back();
```

I don't know why this is the case, but it may be related to redirection which means that when `back()` is called, the previous page is loaded that is only a redirect to the page from where `back()` was called. Calling `back()` a second time loads the page before the redirection page.